# Trying to create simple page: No margins/padding, scroll only main

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a very simple html/css to get the basics correct.

This is actually for my MainLayout.razor page where this will create the framework for each web page with the individual.razor page going inside the `<main>` part. So the actual code in the middle will be:

```
<main>
  @body
</main>
```

I have a couple of problems:

1. The header has a top/bottom margin. Why? shouldn't it be 0?
2. The footer has a top/bottom padding. Again, shouldn't it be 0?
3. Setting the body to have a margin/padding of 0 seems to have no effect. Why?
4. I'm trying to get the vertical scroll to scroll only `<main>` and leave the header & nav always visible (footer appears to always be visible). What else do I need to do?

```css
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.my-header {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.my-nav {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
}

.my-main {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.my-footer {
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <title>Basics</title>
</head>
<body>

<header class="my-header">
    <p>Nicolay Copy</p>
</header>

<nav class="my-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

    <main class="my-main">
        <p>Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.</p>

        <p>Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived, and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle field of that war. We come to dedicate a portion of it, as a final resting place for those who died here, that the nation might live. This we may, in all propriety do.</p>

        <p>But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate we can not consecrate we can not hallow, this ground The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have hallowed it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here; while it can never forget what they did here.</p>

        <p>It is rather for us, the living, we here be dedicated to the great task remaining before us that, from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they here, gave the last full measure of devotion that we here highly resolve these dead shall not have died in vain; that the nation, shall have a new birth of freedom, and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.</p>
    </main>

<footer class="my-footer">
    <p>Lincoln speech text is in the public domain; the organization, remaining text, and photo on this page are copyright 2020 Abraham Lincoln Online. All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

---

I've gotten closer. This solution has one remaining problem, the vertical scroll bar is there even if not needed. Any ideas?

```
<html style="height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
<body style="margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color: blueviolet; color: white">
        Hello Header!
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color: dodgerblue; color: white">
        Hello Navigation!
    </div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
        <div style="height: 100%;">
            <p>Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.</p>

            <p>Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived, and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle field of that war. We come to dedicate a portion of it, as a final resting place for those who died here, that the nation might live. This we may, in all propriety do.</p>

            <p>But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate we can not consecrate we can not hallow, this ground The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have hallowed it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here; while it can never forget what they did here.</p>

            <p>It is rather for us, the living, we here be dedicated to the great task remaining before us that, from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they here, gave the last full measure of devotion that we here highly resolve these dead shall not have died in vain; that the nation, shall have a new birth of freedom, and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color: dodgerblue; color: white">
        Hello Footer!
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The margins are due to margin collapsing - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: Hi David, welcome to frontend:) Some tags have default margin and padding set by the default browser CSS. If you need them to be 0, you need to set them.

Comment: Use your devtools inspector to see what element has the margins on it. This is the easiest way to figure out what is going on.  It comes from the `p` tag inside of `.my-header` for the first example.

Comment: @dantheman if I understand margin collapsing correctly, it's the case of various margin-ed elements laid out vertically where it calculates the max margin needed across all the elements. Simplest example is 12 point type with some 24 point type for one word. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your problems come from what @Azu explains in the comments: Some html tags have default styles set by the browser. These styles come from the [user agent stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#user-agent_stylesheets). To make their life easier, many developers like using a CSS Reset, which is simply a set of CSS rules that are added before your own stylesheet and that take care of clearing out some of the decisions the browser took (for example, the default body margin). Some popular CSS Resets are [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) or the [Meyer Reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Right now, you are still seeing some margins because the user agent stylesheet gives `<p>` tags a top and bottom margin. You can either set all `<p>` tags to not have a margin or use a CSS Reset to do it for you.

I am unsure what you mean with regards to giving the body a margin/padding of 0 not having an effect. I am currently running your code on Chrome and your definition of:

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Has the intended effect of removing the default 8px of margin that Chrome gives the body tag.

With regards to your 4th point and the whole functionality you are looking for, this is how I would accomplish it:

1. In the HTML, move the `nav` into the `header` to keep them together.
2. Give both the `header` and `footer` a `position: sticky` in css to make them stick to the edges of the window. The `header` gets a `top: 0;` so it sticks 0px from the top of the screen. The `footer` gets `bottom: 0` so it sticks 0px from the bottom of the screen.
3. To ensure that the footer stays at the bottom of the screen, regardless of whether there is enough content to push it down there or not, we must give the `main` a minimum height at all times that pushes the footer down. This dynamic height changes depending on the window size, so we add a js function to calculate that height each resize and pass the value to css (with a custom property `--min-h`).
4. Bit of a gotcha for the js function to work properly: the js calculates the height taking into account the space occupied by the scrollbar track on the right. If that track disappears after the js function ran, the calculation will be wrong. Hence we can either add a timeout so the function runs a few seconds after each resize, or we can simply add `overflow-y: scroll` to the body to always reserve a space for the scrollbar to occupy. In my opinion, this is a better idea to reduce [Cumulative Layout Shift](https://web.dev/cls/), so it is what I chose to do. Plus, most users won't even notice the scrollbar track is always there (only the track, **not** the scrollbar)

Here's a snippet with the full implementation:

```js
function setMinContentHeight(){
  //Calculate the minimum height the <main> must occupy to push the footer to the
  //bottom of the window.
  const headerHeight = document.querySelector('header').getBoundingClientRect().height;
  const footerHeight = document.querySelector('footer').getBoundingClientRect().height;
  let minH = window.innerHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight;
  //Pass that value into CSS with a CSS custom property named "--min-h"
  document.body.style.setProperty('--min-h', minH + 'px');
}

function initializeAutoHeightUpdate() {
    setMinContentHeight(); //Set the css property immediately
    //update the value after each window resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', setMinContentHeight);
    
    /* Note: keep in mind that the resize event fires
     * a lot whilst the user changes its size. For
     * more complex interactions, you may want to use
     * a debounce or throttle algorithm to limit
     * unnecessary calls to the function.
     */
}

//As soon as js loads, run this code:
if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) { //If the document has finished loading
        initializeAutoHeightUpdate(); //Start the min height calculator
} else {
        window.addEventListener( 'load', initializeAutoHeightUpdate ); //Wait for the document to load before starting the min height calculator
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0; /*Clear default style for paragraphs */
}

html {
  background-color: lightyellow; /* give this background to the html instead of the main so that it is still visible on overscroll in mobile */
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    --min-h: 0px; /* Give the js calculated variable an initial value */
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

main p:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Give the paragraphs in the main some spacing between paragraphs */
}

.my-header {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.my-nav {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
}

.my-main {
    min-height: var(--min-h); /* set it to always occupy at least the calculated height t push the footer to the bottom of the window. */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.my-footer {
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <title>Basics</title>
</head>
<body>

<header class="my-header">
    <p>Nicolay Copy</p>
    <nav class="my-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>



    <main class="my-main">
        <p>Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.</p>

        <p>Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived, and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle field of that war. We come to dedicate a portion of it, as a final resting place for those who died here, that the nation might live. This we may, in all propriety do.</p>

        <p>But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate we can not consecrate we can not hallow, this ground The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have hallowed it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here; while it can never forget what they did here.</p>

        <p>It is rather for us, the living, we here be dedicated to the great task remaining before us that, from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they here, gave the last full measure of devotion that we here highly resolve these dead shall not have died in vain; that the nation, shall have a new birth of freedom, and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.</p>
    </main>

<footer class="my-footer">
    <p>Lincoln speech text is in the public domain; the organization, remaining text, and photo on this page are copyright 2020 Abraham Lincoln Online. All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this clears up some of your questions! Like some pointed out in the comments, you can use the Web Inspector on your browser to check out which css rules are being applied, so you can better debug your styles.

Comment: I tried that - no luck. The `position: sticky;` for the footer moves it up rather than keeping it at the bottom. And the `overflow: hidden;` in the body removes the vortical scroll bar even when needed. And F12 for main does show `overflow-y: auto;` in combined. Any ideas? TIA

Comment: I modified the answer to cover the footer moving up, please try it out.

Comment: A lot closer! Three problems. First, the scroll bar is there even if not needed. Second, it scrolls the `<nav>` part away. Third, if you make the window small enough, then scrolling all the way down scrolls the `<header>` away too. Any ideas? ps - this is such a common scenario I'm surprised there are not a ton of solutions out there.

Comment: There are actually many solutions out there for this sort of scenario, but since you asked for the basics of css I tried to propose the simplest solutions. The thing about the scrollbar being always present has to do with setting the body to 100% height, which keeps the footer at the bottom. More options to keep the footer at the bottom [here](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/). I didn't notice the question also asked for the nav to stick, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I do not care if the solution matches what I did. My code was my attempt, as a newbie, to implement this. I dislike SO questions where someone didn't try and says give me everything. But if there's a better way to do this, please throw out everything I did and give me that. I want to learn how to do this stuff well. TIA.

Comment: Alright, I updated the answer to the way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

use the ***{}** **universal selector** for more info read:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors

and only main body scroll and  header or footer are always visible..
header and footer set position **sticky**  make sure add one property- **top/right/left/right**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.my-header {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.my-nav {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    position: sticky;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top:20px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
}

.my-main {
    //height:100vh;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    //height: 100%;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.my-footer {   
    position: sticky;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <title>Basics</title>
</head>
<body>

<header class="my-header">
    <p>Nicolay Copy</p>
</header>

<nav class="my-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

    <main class="my-main">
        <p>Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.</p>

        <p>Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived, and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle field of that war. We come to dedicate a portion of it, as a final resting place for those who died here, that the nation might live. This we may, in all propriety do.</p>

        <p>But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate we can not consecrate we can not hallow, this ground The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have hallowed it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here; while it can never forget what they did here.</p>

        <p>It is rather for us, the living, we here be dedicated to the great task remaining before us that, from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they here, gave the last full measure of devotion that we here highly resolve these dead shall not have died in vain; that the nation, shall have a new birth of freedom, and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.</p>
    </main>

<footer class="my-footer">
    <p>Lincoln speech text is in the public domain; the organization, remaining text, and photo on this page are copyright 2020 Abraham Lincoln Online. All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution you provided gets everything (thank you) except it has 2 vertical scroll bars. And I don't see how to reduce it to one??? TIA

Comment: Also, your solution requires a fixed height for the header. My header height is variable (and sometimes 0). Anyway to accomplish that? TIA